# Overwrite or append to existing excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm trying to create a system where excel sheets are sorted by month and year. To do this, I am inserting a dataframe as a new excel sheet if it's input date is different from the last data entry, and appending it to the properly named excel sheet otherwise. For example, if the excel sheet 'June 2016' already exists and the data was inputted in June 2016, the dataframe would be appended to that sheet. If the data was inputted the next month in July 2016, the code searches for a sheet named 'July 2016'. If it doesn't find one, it inputs the data as a new sheet named 'July 2016'. However, I am getting a number of problems. Almost all of these problems go undetected in Visual Studio code, but I will try to open the excel file after and I get error messages saying that the file tag does not match or that the file has been corrupted, or that there is a problem with the content in the workbook and that the application will try to recover what was lost.

```
if exists == True:
    if new_sheet == False:
        #to_append is appended to existing sheet with same name
        #All sheets are resaved in same order
        book = load_workbook(r"transaction.xlsx")
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"transaction.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
        to_append_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=writer.sheets[month_dict_2[str(date.today().month)] + ' ' + str(date.today().year)].max_row)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
    else:
        book = load_workbook(r"transaction.xlsx")
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r"transaction.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = book
        to_append_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=month_dict_2[str(date.today().month)] + ' ' + str(date.today().year), index=False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
else:
    to_append_df.to_excel(r"transaction.xlsx", sheet_name=month_dict_2[str(date.today().month)] + ' ' + str(date.today().year))
```

Here is what I have. The exists variable comes from a try-except code block that checks to see if the xlsx file exists. The new_sheet variable comes from a try-except code block that checks if the sheet for today's month and year exist. If it doesn't exist, that indicates a new month and that a new sheet needs to be made. If it does, there is no need for a new sheet and the data can simply be appended to the corresponding sheet. I am having trouble with the section that appends the dataframe to a preexisting sheet if the data was entered in the same month. I do not necessarily need to append it, as I can also read in the old sheet, append it to the new data in the IDE, and then overwrite the previous sheet with the combined data. However, I don't know how to overwrite a specific sheet. Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: Working with data in an existing workbook can complicate things.  I'd suggest separating the report and data.  Would you consider maintaining your data in one place (a master file - in 1 sheet or a database), and then generating a new (report) workbook with sheets by month year each time you need it in that format.